# Why is the set-method bypassed when property is modified?

Tags: python, get, set, python-decorators

I'm not completely new into Python but sometimes I still have trouble with Python's logic or the way thinks are interpreted. I have the following Class called TestClass in the file testclass.py which has one property x and corresponding get and set methods.

```
class TestClass(object):

    @property
    def x(self):
        print('get x')
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        print('set x')
        self.__x = x
```

If I run a simple example, everything works as it should. So get and set methods are called and print their confirmation messages:

```
>>> from testclass import TestClass
>>> newObject = TestClass()
>>> newObject
<testclass.TestClass object at 0x0298B9D0>
>>> newObject.x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
set x
>>> newObject.x
get x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

My Problem is that if I just want to modify the property by indexing it, the get method is called (what I expect) to get the property from the object, but the set method is bypassed (no set message is printed, but the property is modified):

```
>>> newObject.x[1] = 99
get x
>>> newObject.x
get x
[1, 99, 3, 4]
```

For me, this behaviour is not very logical. I'm coming from Matlab (which is not the most elegant language for OOP). The same structure in Matlab would lead to the following procedure:

- get method for x is been called to get x
- replace the value at the specific index with the new value
- call set method to overwrite the old version of x with the new x

This is just a small example. In my code, i need to get into the set method everytime when the property has been modified. Is there a pythonic way for this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In [Matlab terms](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/copying-objects.html), all Python variables are handle variables and all Python objects are handle objects.

Answer (score 0):

The `property.getter` controls what the property returns when bound to an instance. Once that value is returned, the getter has no control on what you do with it. In particular, if the object was mutable, then you can update it without passing by the `property.setter`.

## Returning a copy of the data

One simple way to fix that is to make your property return a view on the internal data, by example by returning a copy of the data instead of the data itself.

This will force the user to `get` the value, update it and then `set` it back.

```
import copy

class TestClass(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        print('get x')
        return copy.deepcopy(self.__x)

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        print('set x')
        self.__x = copy.deepcopy(x)
```

### Example

```
newObject = TestClass()
newObject.x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
newObject.x[1] = 99
print(newObject.x)
```

### Output

```
set x
get x
get x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

## Using a controller class

Although, it can be costly to copy your data everytime, so an alternate solution is to wrap it in a controller class.

This can be done in a methodical way by inheriting from `collections.MutableSequence` which provides the usual methods available for a `list` based on your implementation of `__delitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__getitem__`, `__len__` and `insert`.

The result will be an object that behaves exactly like a `list`, but with some hooks to check any mutation is valid.

```
from collections import MutableSequence

class ListController(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print('index {} is being set to {}'.format(key, value))
        self._data[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        print('index {} is being deleted'.format(key))
        del self._data[key]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._data[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._data)

    def insert(self, index, value):
        print('item {} is being inserted at index {}'.format(value, index))
        self._data.insert(index, value)


class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    @property
    def x(self):
        print('get x')
        return ListController(self.__x)

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        print('set x')
        self.__x = list(x)
```

### Example

```
newObject = TestClass()
newObject.x[1] = 99
print(newObject.x)
```

### Output

```
get x
index 1 is being set to 99
get x
[1, 99, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the fast answer! Yeah this was exactly what i was recognizing. Too Bad, that the flow is not that get-->mod-->set flow if I change a property by indexing as it is for example in Matlab. So may the way you showed is right for me... I will think about it. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisT No problem. On StackOverflow, do not hesitate to accept an answer that allowed ot fix your issue by clicking the green checkmark on its left. This helps other users find helpful answers as well as provide some good reputation to the asker and the answerer.